# how to display PDF in a php site?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, and not so new to PHP. I am developing a site that has a login for 2 users and once they login, it'll show an optin to view an invoice. I am not making the invoice since I have a stack of invoices already. I want to do it so that once they click on view invoice they can see a PDF. I have searched but I ask you for some idea in the visualization of PDF in codeigniter?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [Google Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer), in case your users don't have a PDF viewer such as Adobe Reader on their computer. You can link to `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=` + the link to your PDF file. Note that the PDF file must be accessible by external servers (not protected by login or htaccess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question but here goes...

If you just want to marshal an existing PDF file via PHP, its basically a case of

1. Send the appropriate "Content-Type" response headers for a PDF file, eg `application/pdf`
2. Deliver the file contents using something like [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: yes I have a stock of invoice(pdf), and in my page (php), I want an option where say "view pdf", and where the user clicks the browser displays a pdf,

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you want to generate pdfs.  There is a library called dompdf that lets you do it quite easily and [there is documentation](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PDF_generation_using_dompdf/) on using that with Codeigniter.

If you're wondering how to link between a pdf and a customer, I'd suggest adding a field in the database to match each customer or perhaps a whole table depending on your use case.

Comment: No, I dont want to generate pdf, I have that pdf, I just want to retrieve from somewhere else and visualize them.

Comment: Somewhere else? Could you explain further?

Comment: I think he has a directory of PDFs already generated and wants to show them to the user in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you have a directory of PDFs that need to be displayed to the user.

This is usually handled by the PDF software. [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) can render the PDF in the browser and so can newer releases of the [Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/) which have PDF viewing built in.

Make sure you send the correct response headers as [Phil Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil-brown) points out and you're all set.

Comment: yes, but another idea will be ok, I mean I would wanna hear another solution :)